# How do a "Find and Replace All" in R?

Tags: r

In R I have a dataframe titled GDP. There are three columns, Country, Year and GDP. One of the countries in the column Country is titled "China (People's Republic of)". I would like to replace that text with text that says "China" for all of its instances. What is the best way of doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to locate the elements that have substring 'China' in the 'Country' column and replace those with 'China'.  It is assumed that the column is `character` class

```
GDP$Country[grep("China", GDP$Country)] <- "China"
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, you can use `str_detect` inside `ifelse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
GDP <- GDP %>% 
     mutate(Country = ifelse(str_detect("(?i)china", "China",Country)))
```

Note that I used "(?i)" to make sure that China might be in lower or upper case.

Comment: (?i) is nice. Thanks!